# MySQL Database UPDATE LIKE Query error

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to update a row using query

```
 update tblstudent a, tmpstudent2013 b set a.dob=b.doa where a.dob like '%2013%' and a.admissionno=b.admissionid;
```

but it is giving me error: Incorrect datetime value "%2013"
plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

```
update tblstudent a, tmpstudent2013 b 
set a.dob = b.doa 
where year(a.dob) = 2013
and a.admissionno = b.admissionid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try : `where YEAR(a.dob) = 2013`